# How do I programmatically invoke Aero Peek on a window?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, aero-peek

Raymond Chen has confirmed that [there is no publicly documented way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/27/10081263.aspx) to do this. Does anyone know an [undocumented solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/27/10081263.aspx#10081644)?

Comment: Damn… He even censored the undocumented functions posted by someone. I have a love/hate relationship with Raymond's blog. Sometimes I feel like a neophyte stumbling upon an old warlock's spell book and sometimes I just wanna punch him in the face.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows aero peek API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450223/windows-aero-peek-api)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same question and began some research on my own, found it eventually.

[Windows aero peek API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450223/windows-aero-peek-api)