# Windows aero peek API

Tags: windows, api, aero, aero-peek

I am trying to use the API for aero peek. With a lot of digging and searching I stumbled upon this piece of code:

```
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#113", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern uint DwmpActivateLivePreview(uint , uint , uint , uint );
```

But I can't get it to work.. I don't know what the parameters are.. I tried some API intercepting tools but that didn't work out. How can I discover how to properly call this API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually solved it my self. I have posted an article on my website about this:
http://www.jesconsultancy.nl/tips-and-tricks/aero-apis.html.
 Unfortunately this is in dutch so here is a bit explaining:

```
 [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#113", SetLastError = true)]
 internal static extern uint DwmpActivateLivePreview(uint switch, IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr c, uint d);

 DwmpActivateLivePreview(1, Handle, topmostWindowHandle, 1);//activate
 DwmpActivateLivePreview(0, Handle, topmostWindowHandle, 1);//deactivate
```

The first parameter is for activating/deactivating the Aero Peek functionality. The second parameter is the handle that Aero peek focuses to. The other <s>two</s> *one* I haven't been able to identify yet.

**Edit:**
After some more messing around with this API I figured out the 3th parameter. When setting the TopMost property of a form, the form still shows sometimes underneath of the aero peek effect. If you pass the handle to that form that needs to be on top of the peek effect as the 3th parameter, and the TopMost property of your form is set to true, your form will be on top of the peek effect.

You can exclude a window from the Aero Peek effect. This is described here: http://huddledmasses.org/fun-with-pinvoke-and-aero-peek/

Comment: Sorry for the late response.. Make sure you compile for AnyCPU, when compiled for x86 under a x64 system the API call won't work. Tested under win 7 and win 8 dev prev.

Comment: Just tested the API on the released Win 8 and it's signature is still correct.

Comment: The API has changed in Win10 (extra argument) - see my answer elsewhere on this page.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older question but, the accepted answer lacks completeness.

Below is the proper usage of the Aero Peek API.

```
    ///<summary>
    /// These flags are used in conjunction with the Aero Peek API.
    /// </summary>
    public enum PeekTypes : long
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This flag is here only for completeness and is not used
        /// </summary>
        NotUsed = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// Denotes that the Peek API is to operate on the desktop
        /// </summary>
        Desktop = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Denotes that the Peek API is to operate on a window.
        /// </summary>
        Window = 3
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the *Almighty* Aero Peek API!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="EM">True if we're going into peek mode; False if we're coming out of it.</param>
    /// <param name="PH">The handle of the window we want to put into peek mode; 
    /// IntPtr.Zero if we're coming out of peek mode or peeking on the desktop.</param>
    /// <param name="C">The handle of the window calling the API method.</param>
    /// <param name="pT">One of the <see cref="PeekTypes"/> enum members. 
    /// Pass <see cref="PeekTypes.Desktop"/> if you want to peek on the desktop and <see cref="PeekTypes.Window"/> if you want to peek on a window. <see cref="PeekTypes.None"/> is unused but, there for completeness.</param>
    /// <param name="hPN0">When going into or out of peek mode, always pass new IntPtr(32) for this parameter.</param>
    /// <param name="iFI0">When going into or out of peek mode, always pass 0x3244 for this parameter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", EntryPoint = "#113", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static extern int InvokeAeroPeek(bool EM, IntPtr PH, IntPtr C, PeekTypes pT, IntPtr hPN0, int x3244);
```

I spent several months reverse engineering most of the cool Windows 7 taskbar API and this is part of my findings. Take it or leave it, this is the proper way to use the Aero Peek API. My "research" was done in 2008, while Windows 7 was still in beta and leaked preview builds were prevalent. For those that might give a shit, this code should work in Windows 8, too. A simple example follows, below:

```
InvokeAeroPeek(enterPeekMode, target, caller, pType, new IntPtr(32), 0x3244);
```

This code is processor agnostic, compile it however you want and it will still work. Win32 and x64 are both welcome.

Comment: The function definition is incorrect in your answer. IDA Pro shows that there are only 4 parameters, not 6. See here for the stack variables in IDA: http://i47.tinypic.com/25a3fpv.png

Comment: I didn't use IDA. IDA didn't show me what I needed to see. This is the proper definition.

Comment: I should add that this very code is being used in a major, commercial, multimonitor taskbar application that is used by 1000's of people, every day.

Comment: That could be, but I dived into the raw disassembly of this function and reverse engineered using IDA Pro. There are simply no 6 parameters. P.s. The fact that your definition is used in a commercial product proves nothing. We are here on StackOverflow where we substantiate what we say.

Answer (score 1):

can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? are you trying to invoke peek or support custom Aero peek in your own application?

if the latter you should reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819048(v=VS.85).aspx and related documentation.

Comment: What I am trying to do is use this API to "peek" to the desktop and other windows. Just like when you go over the "show desktop" button in the right corner of the taskbar in W7.

Comment: in that case unfortunately i can't offer any advice other than: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/27/10081263.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have bad news for everyone actually using this undocumented function.  Windows 10 appears to have added an extra argument to the end.  This likely means your code that run fine under Win7 will probably crash under Win10 because the stack pointer is going to screwed up after you call this function.  Plus, there is a chance that calling this function with a missing stack argument will cause Win10 to deref a bad pointer during the call itself.

I used the following definition.

```
typedef HRESULT (__stdcall *DwmpActivateLivePreview)(BOOL peekOn, HWND hPeekWindow, HWND hTopmostWindow, UINT peekType1or3, UINT_PTR newForWin10);
```

I simply passed zero in this new argument.  Running 64bit code under Win10 64bit, I was able to activate Aero Peek using arguments as described in the other answers on this page.  Running 32bit code under Win10 64bit, I got the same 0x80070018 error I received when running 32bit code under Win7 64bit.

Comment: The signature allready changed under 8.1 I think. I have the correct signature somewhere.. I'l look it up when I get home.

Comment: For me this works only if I compile for x64, not AnyCPU. Also I can't get my app's form to stay topmost even if i pass hTopmostWindow and my form is TopMost=true

Comment: To clarify I am running Windows 10 x64 and I am working on WPF